# Backuping files in a dir if they don't already exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, directory, python-os

I have a Pathfile.dat with File names within that file,
I am trying to copy a backup of the files if one does not exists already

I am having an issue with the function " if files.is_file():"

Below are the Errors that i seem to be getting

/home/admin/Pycharm/backup/test1

not Found
/home/admin/Pycharm/backup/test2

not Found
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘/home/admin/Pycharm/backup/test1’

Try 'cp --help' for more information.

sh: 2: /home/admin/Pycharm/backup/: not found

sh: 3: _copy: not found

cp: missing destination file operand after ‘/home/admin/Pycharm/backup/test2’

Try 'cp --help' for more information.

sh: 2: /home/admin/Pycharm/backup/: not found

sh: 3: _copy: not found

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import logging


filename = 'config.dat'
Configlist = []

def createlist(): 
    with open(filename) as f:
        for item in f:
            Configlist.append(os.path.abspath(item))


def copy():
    for list in Configlist:
        print(list)
        files = Path(list)
        if files.is_file():
            print("Found")
        else:
            print("not Found")
            os.system("cp -R " + list + " /home/admin/Pycharm/backup/ " + list + "_copy ")

createlist()
copy()
```

Comment: Hi David, you question is confusing me. If you append to a list multiple file paths, how are you checking in the copy function one by one the backup itself? -->Path(list) is then wrong and you will not have only a file there. In addition also the os.system command is throwing error because is not proper done. To copy a file you can also use the shutil module.

Comment: Hi Marco the copy function is where i am trying to resolve.. Thanks

Comment: Then also the cp -R is wrong....The meaning   -R, -r, --recursive          copy directories recursively :-) just check the man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't perfectly clear, but there is for sure a problem in the way you do create the string with the cp command

if you do a print of the string used in os.system method, you can see something like this:

```
cp -R /yourpathfile/file /home/admin/Pycharm/backup/ /yourpathfile/file _copy
```

cp takes two arguments as input (source and destination)
When you concat **list** the second time you are using the name with the path, but you need only the file name.

Also there is a *space* at the end of the string "/home/admin/Pycharm/backup/ " so if you concat with the file name it will give you an error

I've tried to adjust the cp part this way, ant this seems to work:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import logging


filename = 'config.dat'
Configlist = []

def createlist():
    with open(filename) as f:
        for item in f:
            Configlist.append((os.path.abspath(item), item))


def copy():
    for (list,name) in Configlist:
        files = Path(list)
        if files.is_file():
            print("Found")
        else:
            print("not Found")
            string = "cp -R " + str(list[:-1]) + " /home/admin/Pycharm/backup/"+name[:-1] + "_copy "
            print(string)
            os.system(string)

createlist()
copy()
```

Comment: thanks for that, did something similar to that i did filepath = ' '.join(list)